# checking lists elements are < a value, do something - Cant seem to work out

Tags: python, list

I have recently came back to python after a year or two and have seem to have lost all ability to code!

I am trying to figure out how to check a list to see if all elements are greater than x, if more than half are less then a value, and if one is less than a value - then do an action reacting to it.

the code I have is

```
score = [80, 35, 50, 70]
actions = [0, 10, 25]
def check(score, actions):
    for i in range(len(score)):
            if (score[i] <= 60 and score[i] > 45):
                score[i] += actions[1]
            if (score[i] <= 45 and score[i] > 30):
                score[i] += actions[2]
check(score, actions)
print (score)
```

I know this is basic, I just looking for a helping hand!

I am also looking to create a function that uses the average of the score minus the action cost to give a reward and just cant seem to get it to work?

this is what I have on it:

```
action_cost = [0, 10, 25]
def rewards(score, reward, action_cost):
    reward == [statistics.mean(score) - action_cost[1]]
    

rewards(score, reward, action_cost)
print(reward)
```

Any help will be great!
Thank you

Comment: can you give the expected output?

Comment: I am not sure what @havingaball is driving at, but the print statement does show the result of updating the score as a result of the check function.  I just don't understand your question.  Can you provide an example of the endmresult you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @havingaball the global variable `score` is changed inside the function. Since it is a list, those changes will reflect in `print`

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my code help you:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array([80, 35, 50, 70])

x = int(input('x: '))
value_1 = int(input('value 1: '))
value_2 = int(input('value 2: '))

values_greater_than_x = array[array > x]
values_lesser_than_value_1 = array[array < value_1]
values_lesser_than_value_2 = array[array < value_2]

if len(values_greater_than_x) == len(array):
    print(f'All elements are greater then {x}')
else:
    print(f'There are elements lesser then {x}')

if len(values_lesser_than_value_1) > len(array)/2:
    print(f'More then a half are lesser then {value_1}')
else:
    print(f'Less then a half are lesser then {value_1}')

if len(values_lesser_than_value_2) >= 1:
    print(f'At least one is lesser then {value_2}')
else:
    print(f'No value is lesser then {value_2}')
```

The only thing that you have to do is to edit that code according your conditions.

Comment: Hi all, 
Thank you for your answers, I feel my question wasn't best worded so hopefully this will make it more clear:
For the first part, I am looking to check an array of scores, ranging from 0 to 100 (meant to be a wellbeing score) and if below certain set scores an action happens to the individual score, such as if below 60 do action 1 but if multiply look to do it to all unless there is more then 2 that are low,  I wish it edit the lowest 2. I also wish it to effect the the other scores. So if one is low, do action 1 that raises there score by 10 but look to lower the other 3 scores by 5

Comment: And for the second part, the reward, I wish it to take the average of the scores minus a cost of the action that in the previous part we have chosen. I don't understand why it is zero, so any help there would be great!

thank you all for your help!